# Should this sentence include a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, slogan

As a sort of company slogan, does the following sentence require a comma - or would it be acceptable - after "good places"?

> "Making good places great places."

Comment: It should NOT. And *places* better not be repeated.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se].

Comment: No comma required; using one would be an error. "She made her home a very welcoming place." _Make_ in this sense takes two objects.

Comment: @Kris: For a slogan, the repetition of _places_ is unexpected and catchy. Just using one is blah.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comma would be confusing. One might think the company is just making **two** things, instead of making one thing **from** another.
For example, replace "good places" by "this" and "great places" by "that":

> "Making this, that."

can be interpreted as "making this **and** that", while

> "Making this that"

would be interpreted as "making *that* **from** *this*".